# Clarification of proof on the completion of a metric space using Cauchy sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

This is in reference to the proof of the [completion theorem of metric spaces](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~nironi/completion.pdf).

(To protect against link rot, here is a copy of the document being referenced:  [page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKnsP.png), [page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJ2TL.png), [page 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYS7S.png))

A proof is given at the bottom of page 2 to "every Cauchy sequence in $\psi[X]$ converges to a point in $X^*$. I don't understand what $\lceil\{z_1,z_2,z_3,\dots\}\rceil$ means. Is it the $\sup$? How is the $\sup$ of a Cauchy sequence of Cauchy sequences defined, especially when there is no ordering in the space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the equivalence class of the Cauchy sequence $(z_1,z_2,\ldots)$ in $X^*$. Look at the very beginning of the proof, where this notation is introduced...

> [image]

Closeup of the notation you're asking about:

> [image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is not, considering the signs $\lceil x\rceil$ are used, and not $[x]$. Moreover, how would saying "all sequences in the cauchy sequence of sequences converge to the same limit" make sense? For example, $\{\{a,a,a\dots\},\{b,b,b\dots\}\dots\}$ is one such cauchy sequence of cauchy sequences, and $a\neq b\neq c$. Hence, to be in one equivalence class they would have to converge to one limit, which they clearly don't.

Comment: @Ayush: You're incorrect, the notation is clearly `\lbrack \rbrack`. Maybe you need a better PDF reader.

Comment: Possible. I'll try opening the document on some other computer. Thanks.

Comment: You also need to read the context carefully. This lemma is not in any way claiming everything is converging to the same limit, because the choice of $z^*$ depends on the sequence you start with.

Comment: @ZevChonoles- Thanks for the edit. I can clearly see the signs you're talking about now.